# Status on a carte de séjour application

Tags: visa, france

Who is responsible for the carte de séjour application processing? Is it the préfecture or some government department in France? I would like to check on my application. From all the googling I've done I can't see anywhere that you can check, so I just wanted to check, before I wait 2 hours at the préfecture. whether there is somewhere else I should be waiting instead, or another department to contact first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the people in charge. The préfecture [de police], being the highest police organization in your region, is handling ID stuff (cartes d'identités, cartes de séjour, permis de conduire, and in the case of passports, they usually have the mairies process the applications: the préfecture is basically the middleman). The actual printing of the cards and passports is of course done by another government body, l'Imprimerie Nationale.

Most probably, having had a little experience with a large préfecture, you're going to get this answer: "Ça sera prêt quand ça sera prêt !" It will be ready when it will be ready! Good luck!